# Example of non-homeomorphic spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Can anyone suggest an example of non-homeomorphic spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $X \times X$ and $Y \times Y$ are homeomorphic?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66007/can-non-homeomorphic-spaces-have-homeomorphic-squares

Comment: I don't think you will get easy examples of that

Comment: An example is the whitehead manifold. If $X$ is the whitehead manifold, then $X \times X \cong \Bbb R^6$ even though $X$ is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 10):

Start with a collection of solid torii $\{T_i\}$ with each $T_{n+1}$ embedded in $T_n$ as follows

[image]

Then the complement of the nested intersection, namely, $\Bbb S^3 \setminus \bigcap T_i$ is called the Whitehead manifold, which we will denote by $W$. $W$ is not homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^3$ as it is not simply connected at infinity (which is surprising, as $W$ is contractible since each $\Bbb S^3\setminus T_n$ is nullhomotopic in $\Bbb S^3 \setminus T_{n+1}$)

In Glimm, *Two cartesian products which are euclidean spaces*, Bull. Soc. Math. France $88 (1961), 131-135$, available [here](https://eudml.org/doc/86982), it is proved that $W \times W \cong \Bbb R^6 \cong \Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^3$.

Thus, $X = W$ and $Y = \Bbb R^3$ provides an example of such a space.

Comment: I think your first line has a typo... $T_{n+1}$ is embedded in $T_n$ ...

Comment: @Anubhav.K Edited, thanks.