# If $\mathbb{R}^{2n} = X \times X$, must $X$ be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

By invoking the Künneth formula for cohomology, one can argue that among the Euclidean spaces only the even-dimensional ones can be the square of some space. Clearly these are indeed squares, as $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \cong \mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

This does not guarantee that there are no other decompositions. Fox showed in 1947 that non-homeomorphic spaces can have homeomorphic squares, and subsequently quite reasonable examples of such spaces have been found.

**Question.** If $\mathbb{R}^{2n} = X \times X$, must $X$ be homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

As a follow-up question, one might consider any decomposition of $\mathbb{R}^N$ as a product $X_1 \times \cdots \times X_k$ and ask whether the $X_i$ must be Euclidean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some searching I found that the question was asked long ago on MathOverflow. A counterexample is given by the Whitehead manifold, whose square is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^6$.

See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60395/square-roots-of-mathbb-r2n

Comment: Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1432122/4280) on this site.